# Split matrix into columns and store in variables

Tags: r, matrix, data-manipulation

I have a matrix with n rows and d columns. For example,

```
n = 100; d = 3
mat = matrix(rnorm(n * d) ncol = d)
```

I need to take the columns of the matrix and assign them to variables x1, x2,..., xd. The number of columns will not be fixed.

I've tried splitting the matrix and assigning it with an mapply statement but no assignment happens:

```
nam = paste0("x", 1:d)
column_vectors = split(x, rep(1:ncol(x), each = nrow(x)))
mapply(FUN = assign, nam, column_vectors)
```

I could do this by brute force but there must be a simpler, cleaner way.

```
nam = paste0("x", 1:d)
column_vectors = split(x, rep(1:ncol(x), each = nrow(x)))
for(i in seq_along(column_vectors)){

  assign(nam[i], column_vectors[[i]]) 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this approach:

```
matList <- unlist(apply(mat, 2, list),  recursive = FALSE)
names(matList) <- paste0("x", 1:d)
list2env(matList, envir = globalenv())
```